# Update a property in models of an ArrayController when using jquery-ui sortable with ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, ember.js

Using http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/ I'm trying to implement a sortable list in a template loaded by an Ember.ArrayController which has an array of Phonenumbers as content :

```
{{#collection App.SortableListView contentBinding="phonenumbers" itemViewClass="App.SortableItem"}}
<b>{{phonenumber.cost}}</b>
{{/collection}}
```

I'm trying to update the 'order' property of each phonenumber after a sort but I can't figure out how to do that :

```
App.SortableListView = JQ.SortableListView.extend({
  items: 'article',

  //update is a jquery ui method called when the sort ends and dom has been updated
  update: function(event, ui) {
    // I would like to update  and persist each phonenumbers model here
  }
});
```

I have tried various things : bindAttr on order, data attributes through jquery, using the contentIndex property of each childView (but it's not updated when sorting)... Everything failed, or was too much complexity for such a simple thing.

I guess I'm missing something obvious, thx for your help.

Answer (score -1):

There is sortProperty method on array controller that do what you want

Comment: I believe he means "sortable" in the jquery ui sense (http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) which means allowing the user to drag the items into whatever order they want.

Comment: @piotr Sorry, but this is not the issue here.